# Find and replace items if they are missing

Tags: regex

I have a text file in a CSV form. Within a quoted (") field I find a carriage return (0D) AND a linefeed (0A). I would like to replace such entries by a linefeed only. The replacement should done IF the two caracters do not follow a quote (what marks the end of a record). So I have not to replace 22 0D 0A but everything with xy 0D 0A -> xy 0A.

Thanks
Urs

Comment: There are several types of regular expression used by the various editors and IDEs. Within which editor or IDE or programming language do you want to do the work?

Answer (score 0):

in javascript :

```
your_string.replace( /([^"])\r\n/ , '$1\n' )
```